# HTML header won't center

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm making a single page scrollable website and want to have the first page to be just a navbar, image, and a header. Now the problem is that I was unable to center the header. Well, at least I got it to center horizontally. But I'm unable to center it vertically. I hope somebody can spot the issue because I've been puzzling this annoying issue for hours.

This: https://startbootstrap.com/previews/grayscale/ is the idea I'm going for, to make it clear.

Here is the code

```css
/*body {
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(#F9774C, .75), rgba(#802A0C, .85));
        background-image: url("Background_photo_2.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        box-shadow: 4056 3000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) inset;
          /* Center and scale the image nicely 
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 50%;
                }*/ 
    
    nav {
        font-size: medium;
    }
    
    .nav-item a{
        color: white !important
    }
    
     body, html {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
     }
    
    /*styles background image*/
    .bg-img {
        /*background-image: url("Background_photo_2.jpg");*/
    
        height: 100%;
    
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    
        box-shadow: 4000px 3000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset;
        
    }          
    
    /* use this to change the general fonts */
    p, h1  {
        color: white;
        
    }
    
    /* arranges navbar items to right */
    ul {
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    
    .bg-img.container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    #content {
        width: 100%;
        height: 85%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    /*.container-fluid {
        width: 70%;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Home - Both Sides Now </title>
  <!-- BOOTSTRAP CDN IMPLEMENTATION-->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Links to the stylesheet-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bg-img">
    <!--This is the navbar-->
    <div class="container col-md-10">
      <nav class="navbar transparant navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="logotransparant.gif" class="d-inline-block align-top" width="60" height="60"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

    </div>

    <header class="masthead d-flex h-100 justify-content-center">
      <div class="container ">
        <div class="mx-auto text-center">
          <h1 class="mx-auto my-0 text-uppercase">Grayscale</h1>
          <h2 class="text-white-50 mx-auto mt-2 mb-5">A free, responsive, one page Bootstrap theme created by Start Bootstrap.</h2>
          <a href="#about" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger">Get Started</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: In your example header is not vertically centered, it is horizontally fixed on top and on scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
nav {
            font-size: medium;
        }
        
        .nav-item a {
            color: white !important
        }
        
        body,
        html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        }
        /*styles background image*/
        
        .bg-img {
            /*background-image: url("Background_photo_2.jpg");*/
            height: 100%;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            box-shadow: 4000px 3000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset;
        }
        /* use this to change the general fonts */
        
        p,
        h1 {
            color: white;
        }
        /* arranges navbar items to right */
        
        ul {
            margin-left: auto;
        }
        
        .bg-img.container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        
        #content {
            width: 100%;
            height: 85%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        /*.container-fluid {
        width: 70%;
    } */
        
        .mx-auto {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home - Both Sides Now </title>
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP CDN IMPLEMENTATION-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Links to the stylesheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="bg-img">
        <!--This is the navbar-->
        <div class="container col-md-10">
            <nav class="navbar transparant navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="logotransparant.gif" class="d-inline-block align-top" width="60" height="60"></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

        </div>

        <header class="masthead d-flex h-100 justify-content-center">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="mx-auto text-center">
                    <h1 class="my-0 text-uppercase">Grayscale</h1>
                    <h2 class="text-white-50 mt-2 mb-5">A free, responsive, one page Bootstrap theme created by Start Bootstrap.</h2>
                    <a href="#about" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger">Get Started</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it for me, can you maybe explain what you changed and why my code didn't work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SjosSivlingworkz Brother, here time matters, I added an answer at 19:45 and hamidrun added an answer at 19:57 with the same answer. so the accepted answer should be mine, so, please accept my answer as the correct answer and next time please see it before accepting any answer.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use styles. Bootstrap does it for you :

```
<header class="row align-items-center masthead d-flex h-100 justify-content-center">
  <div class="container ">
    <div class="mx-auto text-center">
      <h1 class="mx-auto my-0 text-uppercase">Grayscale</h1>
      <h2 class="text-white-50 mx-auto mt-2 mb-5">A free, responsive, one page Bootstrap theme created by Start Bootstrap.</h2>
      <a href="#about" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger">Get Started</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Add two classes to **header** div that I have added above.

**Note** : after you added row class maybe you have to add **col** to your content elements.

Comment: Now the header isn't fixed to the top. It instead creates whitespace at the bottom and is slightly miscentered towards the bottom. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Where is the white space exactly? Just top of the header?

Comment: Could you please insert an image?

Comment: The white space is under the header and under the image, check my original post, there is now an image.

Comment: Fortunately, you got your answer

Answer (score 0):

There is two option to do vertical center

- you need to give the position to your `navigation bar` so it does not calculate in `flexbox`, for that you need to change your code a little bit.
- you need to cut out your `navigation bar` height from your page, so it does not calculate in `flexbox`, I calculated your navbar height and its equal to `86px` so, I will cut `172px` from your page

Now you need to choose best way, from my side, first is better than second.

---

#### 1st Idea

Just added `align-items-center vh-100` in `masthead` class tag and added CSS

```
.bg-img > .container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```css
/*body {
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(#F9774C, .75), rgba(#802A0C, .85));
        background-image: url("Background_photo_2.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        box-shadow: 4056 3000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) inset;
          /* Center and scale the image nicely 
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 50%;
                }*/ 
    
    nav {
        font-size: medium;
    }
    
    .nav-item a{
        color: white !important
    }
    
     body, html {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
     }
    
    /*styles background image*/
    .bg-img {
        /*background-image: url("Background_photo_2.jpg");*/
    
        height: 100%;
    
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    
        box-shadow: 4000px 3000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset;
        
    }          
    
    /* use this to change the general fonts */
    p, h1  {
        color: white;
        
    }
    
    /* arranges navbar items to right */
    ul {
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    
    .bg-img.container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    #content {
        width: 100%;
        height: 85%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    /*.container-fluid {
        width: 70%;
    }*/
    
    .bg-img > .container {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Home - Both Sides Now </title>
  <!-- BOOTSTRAP CDN IMPLEMENTATION-->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Links to the stylesheet-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bg-img">
    <!--This is the navbar-->
    <div class="container col-md-10">
      <nav class="navbar transparant navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="logotransparant.gif" class="d-inline-block align-top" width="60" height="60"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

    </div>

    <header class="masthead d-flex vh-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <div class="container ">
        <div class="mx-auto text-center">
          <h1 class="mx-auto my-0 text-uppercase">Grayscale</h1>
          <h2 class="text-white-50 mx-auto mt-2 mb-5">A free, responsive, one page Bootstrap theme created by Start Bootstrap.</h2>
          <a href="#about" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger">Get Started</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</div>

</html>
```

---

#### 2nd Idea

Just added `align-items-center` in `masthead` class tag and added CSS

```
.masthead {
    height: calc(100vh - 172px);
}
```

```css
/*body {
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(#F9774C, .75), rgba(#802A0C, .85));
        background-image: url("Background_photo_2.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        box-shadow: 4056 3000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) inset;
          /* Center and scale the image nicely 
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 50%;
                }*/ 
    
    nav {
        font-size: medium;
    }
    
    .nav-item a{
        color: white !important
    }
    
     body, html {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
     }
    
    /*styles background image*/
    .bg-img {
        /*background-image: url("Background_photo_2.jpg");*/
    
        height: 100%;
    
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    
        box-shadow: 4000px 3000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset;
        
    }          
    
    /* use this to change the general fonts */
    p, h1  {
        color: white;
        
    }
    
    /* arranges navbar items to right */
    ul {
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    
    .bg-img.container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    #content {
        width: 100%;
        height: 85%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    /*.container-fluid {
        width: 70%;
    }*/
    
    .masthead {
      height: calc(100vh - 172px);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Home - Both Sides Now </title>
  <!-- BOOTSTRAP CDN IMPLEMENTATION-->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Links to the stylesheet-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bg-img">
    <!--This is the navbar-->
    <div class="container col-md-10">
      <nav class="navbar transparant navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="logotransparant.gif" class="d-inline-block align-top" width="60" height="60"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

    </div>

    <header class="masthead d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <div class="container ">
        <div class="mx-auto text-center">
          <h1 class="mx-auto my-0 text-uppercase">Grayscale</h1>
          <h2 class="text-white-50 mx-auto mt-2 mb-5">A free, responsive, one page Bootstrap theme created by Start Bootstrap.</h2>
          <a href="#about" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger">Get Started</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</div>

</html>
```